# Angular - Component should render currency or date values

Tags: angular

I have an Angular component and it is just a label which renders a value and if it has an associated pipe, the output of the pipe should be rendered as value of the label. But I don't want to declare all the pipes in the component. Currently I would like to use the currency pipe and the date pipe with their parameters. But maybe I can extend the component to use other pipes.

Would you pass the pipes as input parameter of the component or what would be your approach to achieve that? Any idea?

**Update**
Here you have my StackBlitz. If you can see, I pass a type of a pipe and its params as parameters, if I want to use any pipe. The component could also render a label without using a pipe.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-label-render

app.component.ts

```
<app-custom-label value="10000" title="My Title for a Currency render" datatype="currency" param="EUR"></app-custom-label>

<app-custom-label value="01.10.1980" title="My Title for a Date render" datatype="date" param="dd MMMM"></app-custom-label>
```

custom.label.component.html

```
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
<label> {{ value }} </label>
```

custom.label.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';
import { DataType } from './type';
import { CurrencyPipe, DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeDe from '@angular/common/locales/de';
import localeDeExtra from '@angular/common/locales/extra/de';

registerLocaleData(localeDe, 'de-DE', localeDeExtra);

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-label',
  templateUrl: './custom.label.component.html'
})
export class CustomLabelComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() value: string;
  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() datatype: DataType;
  @Input() param: string;


  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(){
    if (this.datatype === "currency") {
      this.value = (new CurrencyPipe('de-DE')).transform(this.value, this.param, true);
    } else if (this.datatype === "date") {
      this.value = (new DatePipe('de-DE')).transform(this.value, this.param);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you don’t like the pipes available, you can always create your own pipe. I wouldn’t pass the pipe as an input. Try and keep it simple. Make your component as dumb as possible. Can you make a stackblitz so we can see what you are attempting?

Comment: I added my Stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a component for transforming value seems to be an overkill, I am saying this in light of the following:

- A **pipe** gets data as an input, transforms it and outputs this data in another way.
- A **Directives** adds behavior to an existing DOM element or an existing component instance
- A **component**, rather than adding/modifying behavior, actually creates its own view (hierarchy of DOM elements) with attached behavior.
- referencing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41966635/angular-directives-vs-pipes) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680244/directive-v-s-component-in-angular);

Check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a4hycf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom.pipe.ts) on using a custom pipe to achieve your objective - look forward to other experts for their input on this understanding and solution also.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { CurrencyPipe, DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeDe from '@angular/common/locales/de';
import localeDeExtra from '@angular/common/locales/extra/de';
registerLocaleData(localeDe, 'de-DE', localeDeExtra);


@Pipe({name: 'customConvert'})
export class customConvertPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number, passedObj:string): any {
    console.log( value);
    var newObj = JSON.parse(passedObj);
    console.log(newObj);
    if (newObj.datatype === "currency") {
      return (new CurrencyPipe('de-DE')).transform(value, newObj.param, true);
    } else if (newObj.datatype === "date") {
      return (new DatePipe('de-DE')).transform(value, newObj.param);
    } else if (newObj.datatype === "string"){
      return value;
    }
  }
}
```